# How can I just subscribe only the JSON that has "category":2?

Tags: angular

Assuming that I want to subscribe these JSONs:

```
[
            {
                "id": 667,
                "image": "https://ae0g",
                "description": "GRE",
                "price": "USD .11",
                "buy": "https://sn",
                "category": 1
            },
            {
                
                "image": "https://ae04.",
                "description": "10/13 ",
                "price": ".18",
                "buy": "https://",
                "category": 2
            }
]
```

with this code in Angular:

```
 ngOnInit() {
  this.api.getApi()
  .subscribe(    
    data => this.todo=data 
  );}
```

How can I just subscribe only the JSON that has `"category":2`?

Answer (score 1):

We could use rxjs/filter to filter out items you don't need.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter

```js
 ngOnInit() {
  this.api.getApi().pipe(filter(item => item.category === 2))
  .subscribe(    
    data => this.todo = data;
  );}
```