# In the service is it possible to just get the objectss that have category of 2?

Tags: angular

After getting the data in Angular, some of the objects have category of 1 and some of them have category of 2.

In the service is it possible to just get the objects that have category of 2?

service:

```
export class ApiService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }
  private URL="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/"
  getApi():Observable<any>{
   
    return this.http.get (this.URL) 

  }
```

interface:

```
export interface Product
{
    id:number;
    image:string;
    description:string;
    buy:string;
    category:number;

}
```

component:

```
 todo?:Product[];
 ngOnInit() {
  this.api.getApi() 
  .subscribe(    
    data  => this.todo=data 
  );}


}
```

Comment: …yes? Filter the returned data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I just subscribe only the JSON that has "category":2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72733333/how-can-i-just-subscribe-only-the-json-that-has-category2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple ways to do this.

The best way imho is to filter at there server side, however I do not see any code for that part, so I'll give you an example for the filtering at client side:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.api.getApi()
  .pipe(
     filter(res => res.category === 2)) 
  .subscribe(    
    data  => this.todo=data 
  )
}
```

The data will be an array that you can show in your HTML like this:

```html
<ul>
   <li *ngFor=let item of data>{{item.description}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If I do that, I'm not able to display other objects like `{{todo?.description}}`.

Comment: Because `this.todo` will be `data`. And `data` is an array in which you have one object `[{}]`. It could be `this.todo=data[0]`, then you can access `this.todo` obj's properties.